# Disable javascript with selenium WebDriver?

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have a program that tests some of our sites with javascript disabled. It worked well, until we updated from WebDriver 2.4.5 to the latest. Now I get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference javascript.enabled may not be overridden: frozen value=true, requested value=false`

It looks like the argument to disable JS is no longer allowed. I can't downgrade the WebDriver because the earlier versions don't work correctly with our updated Firefox.

What are my options for testing with JS disabled? I know Chrome never worked before, and now Firefox doesn't. I tried searching for "webdriver js disabled" but the results just bring back the `javascript.enabled, false` argument that no longer seems to work.

Comment: I just tried using HTMLUnit with js disabled. And it works, however screenshots are not possible with it since it doesn't render anything (and I need to be able to take screenshots)

Answer (score 1):

Best I could come up with is;

Create a new Firefox profile called NoJs by starting it with -P

Go to about:config and disable javascript there

Use this profile in selenium

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("NoJs");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```